# Get data from multiple table with LIKE

Tags: php, sql

I made a site with articles and I want to make a search area.

So I create all but block on SQL I would like to retrieve the title of articles that contains 'MSA' or others in 6 different table

Table name:

```
stiga
stihl
staub
goldoni
echo
toro
```

I tried with LIKE but he tells me an ambiguous field result :/

Answer (score 4):

Use `union all`:

```
select title from stiga where title like '%MSA%'
union all
select title from stihl where title like '%MSA%'
union all
. . .
```

Comment: Thank you, it works great!
I am a beginner in SQL is complicate at first ^ ^ thank you again!